# Android - Accessing storage locations

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok, Quick heads up that I am new to android programming.
I have very basic experience with java from uni.
I've recently been messing around with android studio and app building for my Samsung Galaxy Tab. 
Sorry if this has been asked before but i couldn't see it.

I have tried to make an app that displays all the names of files on my SD card. Just at the top level. I made a quick interface with just a button and a text view to start (i'm away a single text view wont display a list but had problems but i got to that anyway)

ended up with the following code.

```
*public void ShowFolder(View view){
    TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View);
    root = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().toString());

    File[] Files;
    Files = root.listFiles();

    String[] File_List;
    File_List = root.list();*
```

I then ran this using the debugger to see what ended up in both the array lists.
I ran this code three times over but varied the "Environment.getRootDirectory" to "getExternalStorageDirectory()" and "getDataDirectory()".

Only the getRootDirectory version will return anything.In both other instances the debugger shows NULL for both Files and Files_list.
I know they are valid locations because used those commands then outputted to strings which i can manually find on my tablet with a file browser.

So, simply put, why dont all three of these options return file lists?
My first thought it permissions but I was unsure how to confirm this.

(Sorry for the long post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `toString()` to create `File`. `getRootDirectory()` already returns `File` object.

Try something like this:

```
File root = Environment.getRootDirectory();
String[] rootList = root.list();
File[] rootListFiles = root.listFiles();
```

Also you need to obtain [`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission as you can see here in the docs of [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: Ok, made those changes. 
so thats bad practise on my part rather than an error ?

Any info on why getExternalStorageDirectory() and getDataDirectory() wont return any entries in the array lists?

Comment: I've edited my answer with additional info on possibly missing Permission.

Comment: Thanks, with the permissions added I can return values for all 3 of the directory functions. 
Are there any other similar functions for returning directory paths?
specifically one that returns the pathway to my SD card. I also tried looking this up but it seems the getExternalStorageDirectory() function does this some of the time and not others depending on what device is being used.